# Google Play Services only recognizes deleted account; cannot update any apps

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I got my Samsung Galaxy J7 in September and signed in using my primary, personal Google account ("A"). In early November, I downloaded Skype for Business for my job purposes, and created a new Google account out of habit ("B"). **I DID NOT DOWNLOAD ANY OTHER APPS USING THIS ACCOUNT.** A few weeks later, my boss informed me that a Google account is in violation of company policy, so I apologized and permanently deleted the account.

After the account was permanently deleted, I got an unclear-able notification saying ["Account Action Required."](https://prnt.sc/lqszq7) Going to Google Play Services (which I didn't even know existed until then) led to a screen which "prompted" me to sign in with account B, but highlighting the email address [does not pop the keyboard up.](https://prnt.sc/lqt6xi) I have no choice but to sign in to that account, [with predictable results.](https://prnt.sc/lqt6th)

Now account A is experiencing issues, which I'm positive are linked to this problem. [I cannot check for updates](https://prnt.sc/lqt8cz), updates in general seem to have been disabled, and my list of installed apps [appears to be blank](https://prnt.sc/lqt8z1), even though they all show up [in my library.](https://prnt.sc/lqt9bf) Again, **all of these apps were downloaded on account A.**

Does someone help me resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm no longer using GApps – but a step that often helps is clearing cache (and optionally data) from the Google Play app and, if that didn't help, also from the Google Play Services app. In the worst case, remove all Google accounts from the device, then re-add "A". The absolute last resort would be a factory reset, but I'd hope you won't need to go that far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be happen because you deleted your account permanently from the web but that account still saved in the device and triggering a force sign in to identify you.

Follow these steps:

For Samsung specific-

1. Open Settings》Cloud and accounts 》Accounts》Google.
2. Now click the account that you have deleted permanently.

   3. Tap 3 dots on the upper right corner and choose ***Remove account.***

It must work.

Else last option would be a factory reset and set up device again.